# Angular 6 pagination with ng-bootstrap of fetched data from Api

Tags: javascript, angular

Can someone help me fix my code for pagination?

There is a service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable ()

export class MovieRequestService {
  private moviesList = `https://yts.am/api/v2/list_movies.json`;
  private movieDetails = `https://yts.am/api/v2/movie_details.json`;
  constructor(private myHttp: HttpClient )  {

  }

  getListOfMovies(page: number, collectionSize: number): any {
    return this.myHttp.get(`${this.moviesList}?limit=${collectionSize}&page=${page}`);
  }
  getMovieDetails(id: number): any {
    return this.myHttp.get(`${this.movieDetails}?movie_id=${id}&with_images=true&with_cast=true`);
  }
}
```

Second file is component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MovieRequestService } from '../../shared/services/movie-request.service';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { ContentChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbPagination } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie-list',
  templateUrl: './movie-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie-list.component.css']
})
export class MovieListComponent implements OnInit {
  @ContentChild(NgbPagination) pagination: NgbPagination;
  page = 1;
  collectionSize = 40;
  movies: any[] = new Array;
  constructor(private movieService: MovieRequestService, private http: HttpClient) {
    this.getPageFromService();
  }

  getPageFromService() {
    this.movieService.getListOfMovies(this.page, this.collectionSize).subscribe(response => this.movies = response.data.movies);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

And last one is html of the component:

```html
<div class="row" >
  <div class="col-sm-3 flex-md-wrap" *ngFor="let movie of movies">
    <div class="card mb-3">
      <a >
        <figure class="figure">
          <img src="{{movie.medium_cover_image}}" alt="{{movie.title}}" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded mx-auto d-block" width="253">
          <figcaption class="figure-caption">
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </a>
      <a routerLink="movie/{{movie.id}}"><div>{{ movie.title | json}}
      </div></a>
      <div class="mb-4">{{ movie.year | json}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ngb-pagination
    class="d-flex justify-content-center"
    (pageChange)="getPageFromService()"
    [collectionSize]="collectionSize"
    [(page)]="page"
    [boundaryLinks]="true">
  </ngb-pagination>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

As you can see, there are only 4 pages of paginations but there should be more than 200 (db has 8973 movies with limit of 40 per page).

Example of *json* from *api*:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `collectionSize` is 40. By default page size is 10. Thus you see 4 pages.

You need to change your `collectionSize` = your movie count and `pageSize` of 40.

Edit:

```
this.movieService
  .getListOfMovies(this.page, this.pageSize)
  .subscribe(response => {
    this.movies = response.data.movies;
    this.collectionSize = response.data.movie_count;
  });
```

Edit 2:
Seems like `page` doesn't get updated due to the change detection, you need to pass the emitted event from `pageChange`, you can see that if you log your `this.page` it is always returning the previous value.

On your HTML:

```
 <ngb-pagination
(pageChange)="getPageFromService($event)"
[pageSize]="pageSize"
[(page)]="page"
[maxSize]="5"
[rotate]="true"
[collectionSize]="collectionSize"
[boundaryLinks]="true"
></ngb-pagination>
```

On `.ts`

```
getPageFromService(page) {
    this.movieService.getListOfMovies(page, this.pageSize).subscribe(response => {
      this.movies = response.data.movies;
      this.collectionSize = response.data.movie_count;
    });
}
```

Comment: Similar how you store your `movie`. Create another variable to store the count from the response.

Comment: i need to do new function in service e.t.c. ?

Comment: now i have problem. so when i fetch data first time i directly fetch from page 1 and when i'm try to click to next page it's bring me to page one and only after this to page to for example

Comment: Having a hard time understanding what issue you are having, could you make a stackblitz demonstrating the issue?

Comment: @JacklinTrio, I've updated my answer for your issue you were having.

Comment: thank's you a lot. maybe you can help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52590032/angular-6-forms-fetch-object-into-input ?